# how to know the id of user created by python social auth for new and returning users?

Tags: django, django-socialauth, python-social-auth

I am using `python-social-auth` for letting user log in through fb, google and linkedin.
When a user is created by one of this backends and is stored in database.
We have the following: (Using `django-mongodb-engine` not `mongoengine`)

**user_register_registration**(Custom User model)

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "abcdxxxxxxx344"
    },
    "username": "something",
    "utype": "AB",
    "email": "abc@abc.com",
    "last_login": {
        "$date": "2014-12-10T07:12:41.848Z"
    },
    "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

and **social_auth_usersocialauth**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "yxzxxxxxxx123"
    },
    "extra_data": "access token etc",
    "user_id": {
        "$oid": "abcdxxxxxxx344"
    },
    "uid": "abc@abc.com",
    "provider": "google-oauth2"
}
```

**django_session**

```
{
    "_id": "pqrxxxxxx543",
    "expire_date": {
        "$date": "2014-12-10T08:12:41.853Z"
    },
    "session_data": "session data"
}
```

How can i know which user was created using these backends.

Method I applied to solve this:

```
s = UserSocialAuth.objects.last()
ssid = s.user_id
```

OR

```
s = Registration.objects.last()
request.session['SSID'] = s.id
ssid = UserSocialAuth.objects.get(user_id=s.id)
```

This doesn't seem to the right way. I am concerned about concurrency problem and returning users.

This idea fails for `returning users`

Can we know session key or anything?

Comment: Do you wish to determine the last User created using this infrastructure? or a list of users?

Comment: Last user who was created...

Comment: there may be a problem that before fetching the data for prevoius user some other users data is filled up at last.. is this possible?

Comment: There are variables in session data named "_auth_user_id" & "social_auth_last_login_backend". Is that what you are looking for?